# EMR PySpark structured streaming takes too long to read from big s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a two computer EMR cluster with PySpark installed reading data from s3. The code is a very simple filter and transform operation using `sqlContext.readStream.text` to fetch data from the bucket. The bucket is ~10TB large and has around 75k files organized by `bucket/year/month/day/hour/*` with `*` representing up to 20 files of 128MB in size. I started the streaming task by providing the bucket `s3://bucket_name/dir/` and letting PySpark read all files in it. It's now being almost 2 hours, the job hasn't even started consuming data from s3 and the network traffic as reported by Ganglia is minimal.

I'm scratching my head about why is this process so slow and how can I increase its speed, since currently the machines I'm paying for are basically idle.

When I use `.status` and `.lastProgress` to track the status I get the following responses respectively:

```
{'isDataAvailable': False,
 'isTriggerActive': True,
 'message': 'Getting offsets from FileStreamSource[s3://bucket_name/dir]'}
```

and

```
{'durationMs': {'getOffset': 207343, 'triggerExecution': 207343},
 'id': '******-****-****-****-*******',
 'inputRowsPerSecond': 0.0,
 'name': None,
 'numInputRows': 0,
 'processedRowsPerSecond': 0.0,
 'runId': '******-****-****-****-*******',
 'sink': {'description': 'FileSink[s3://dest_bucket_name/results/file_name.csv]'},
 'sources': [{'description': 'FileStreamSource[s3://bucket_name/dir]',
   'endOffset': None,
   'inputRowsPerSecond': 0.0,
   'numInputRows': 0,
   'processedRowsPerSecond': 0.0,
   'startOffset': None}],
 'stateOperators': [],
 'timestamp': '2018-02-19T22:31:13.385Z'}
```

Any ideas of what could be causing the data consumption to take so long? Is this normal behaviour? Am I doing something wrong? Any tips on how can this process be improved?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some basic working example of your code? This way I might be able to answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Spark checks for files in the source folder and tries to discover [partitions by checking sub-folders' names to correspond pattern "column-name=column-value"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets).

Since your data is partitioned by date then files should be structured in something like this: `s3://bucket_name/dir/year=2018/month=02/day=19/hour=08/data-file`.